# why does this this condition work in return statement without else?

Tags: javascript, function

I think that b should always be returned but the condition work both way. I read it is recommended not to use it after return statements in c.well now I got it return stops the function.

```
function min(a,b) {
  if(a<b) return a;
  return b; 
}

min(20,94);//20
min(20,4);//4
```

Comment: Not sure I understand the question.  Your code will return the value of a whenever the value of a is less than the value of b, and will return b whenever the value of a is greater than or equal to the value of b.  That appears to be the intended result?

Comment: When you return, it will exit the function so if a is returned, the code will never get to b

Comment: Aaah.  Now I see what you mean.  @Huangism cleared that up.

Comment: why you think that _b should always be returned_, you have simple condition if _a_ less than _b_ return _a_

Comment: If you find it more readable, you could also use a conditional statement, e.g. return (a < b) ? a : b;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `return` breaks out of the function completely. `return b` is never hit if `return a` has already been hit, and `return a` will only fire if `a` is less than `b`.

> The return statement ends function execution and specifies a value to be returned to the function caller.
>
> — [MDN's notes on `return`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return)

In pseudo-code, your code snippet essentially performs the following:

1. It takes two arguments, `a` and `b`.
2. It then checks if `a` is less than `b` and if so, returns `a` - the function ends here.
3. If the check in part 2. fails, it makes it to this part and returns `b`. The function ends here.

`min(20, 94)`

Here `20` (`a`) is less than `94` (`b`), so part 2's check evaluates to true and `20` is returned. Nothing else happens.

`min(20, 4)`

Here `20` (`a`) is *not* less than `4` (`b`), so part 2's check evaluates to false and we move on to part 3 where `4` is returned. Nothing else happens.

Comment: This is simple question, and answer. Why so much upvotes for 48k user? World is crazy, and question is really logically dumb

Comment: @evc 1. Simple questions aren't necessarily bad questions. 2. Three upvotes means three people felt my answer solved OP's problem. It has nothing to do with reputation.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly Well, i don't know, sometimes i struggle for the answer, really, make some researches and modify answer, and get only few points(sometimes 0 pts although OP chooses mine). But this question is so dumb, and you got 3 upvotes for simple answer, how do you do this? (And someone upvoted question, really?) (I mean why would you even answer that easy question with 48k rep)

Comment: @evc Because different questions draw different amounts of attention. I already have the [Unsung Hero badge](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/226/unsung-hero?userid=1317805) myself, so I certainly know what it feels like to receive no upvotes. Furthermore it's often the simple questions which go down the best as people don't have to learn all that much about the question to know what it's asking. Nowadays simple questions like this are often closed as duplicates of much older questions, but sometimes new ones appear which have slipped through the net.